# How to group object of the class by attribute and plot data using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a class:

```
class Spatial(object):
    def __init__(self, id_jenis, jenis, lat, long):
        self.id_jenis=id_jenis
        self.jenis=jenis
        self.lat= lat
        self.long=long

data = []
data.append(Spatial(1,'battery', 1 , 3.4))
data.append(Spatial(2,'rusa', 5 , 3.4))
data.append(Spatial(3,'rusa', 5 , 6.4))
```

How to group object of that class by `jenis` and plot my object `Lat` is `y` and `Long` is `X` . In my code, how to replace `#Lat#`,`#Long#`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(dataPerJenis)))

for k, col in zip(dataPerJenis.keys(),colors):
     plt.plot('#Lat#','#Long#' , 'o', markerfacecolor=col, markeredgecolor='k', markersize=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the `itertools` module and [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) from the operator module.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> class Spatial(object):
...     def __init__(self, id_jenis, jenis, lat, long):
...         self.id_jenis=id_jenis
...         self.jenis=jenis
...         self.lat= lat
...         self.long=long
...
>>> data = []
>>> data.append(Spatial(1,'battery', 1 , 3.4))
>>> data.append(Spatial(2,'rusa', 5 , 3.4))
>>> data.append(Spatial(3,'rusa', 5 , 6.4))
>>> lat = []
>>> long = []
>>> for grp, data in groupby(sorted(data, key=attrgetter('jenis')), key=attrgetter('jenis')):
...     for element in data:
...         lat.append(element.lat)
...         long.append(element.long)
...
>>> lat
[1, 5, 5]
>>> long
[3.4, 3.4, 6.4]
```

Then you can plot your data like this:

```
plt.plot(lat, long , 'o', markerfacecolor=col, markeredgecolor='k', markersize=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through your `data`, check that it's part of the right group, and `print` the attribute of interest:

```
for datum in data:
    if datum.jenis == 'rusa':
        print datum.long
```

As per the substantive edit to the question that changes a need to print into a need to store certain values for use with `numpy` and `matplotlib`, replace `print datum.long` with `jen[datum.jenis] = (datum.lat, datum.long)` and initialize the necessary dictionary:

```
jen = {}
for datum in data:
    if datum.jenis == 'rusa':
        jen[datum] = (datum.lat, datum.long)
```

Comment: thank you. but i still can't use your way to my case. Actually I want to plot data. I'll edit my question....

Comment: @ErnaPiantari - In the future, please include in your questions a real [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that _accurately represents_ the issue you're facing. Substantive changes to a question after it has been answered can invalidate answers, resulting in a question and answer(s) that don't seem to belong together and aren't useful. On future questions, if you realize that the question you actually ask does not match the question you meant to ask, accept your preferred answer that answers _the original question_ and then ask your intended question in a new question.

Comment: sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem. May be my solution is naive, but for this time, it's work well.

```
__author__ = 'erna'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psycopg2
import numpy as np

try:
 conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='Chicago_crime' user='postgres'       host='localhost' password='1234'")
except :
print "I'm unable to connect to the database"
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT id_objek, primary_descript, lat, long from data_crime_id_339""")

class Spatial(object):
def __init__(self, id_jenis, jenis, lat, long):
    self.id_jenis=id_jenis
    self.jenis=jenis
    self.lat= lat
    self.long=long

#############data
dataPerJenis=dict()
Lat=[]
Long=[]
for id_jenis, jenis, lat, long in cur.fetchall():
  if jenis not in dataPerJenis.keys():
    dataPerJenis.setdefault(jenis,[])
    dataPerJenis[jenis].append(Spatial(id_jenis,jenis,lat,long))
  else:
    dataPerJenis[jenis].append(Spatial(id_jenis,jenis,lat,long))



### plot data
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(dataPerJenis)))

for k, col in zip(dataPerJenis.keys(),colors):
  Long=[]
  Lat=[]
  for x in dataPerJenis[k]:
    Long.append(x.long)
    Lat.append(x.lat)
  plt.plot( Lat,Long , 'o', markerfacecolor=col, markeredgecolor='k', markersize=3)

plt.show()
```